# Logging UIButton titleLabel displays CALayer.... not string

Tags: iphone, uibutton, title, mkannotation, ibaction

I'm trying to get the titleLabel string of a UIButton, but it's logging as a CALayer... any suggestions?

```
//ADD TWT BUTTON
    twitter_share = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 44, 29, 28)];
    twitter_share.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [twitter_share setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_annotation_share_twitter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    twitter_share.titleLabel.hidden = YES;
    twitter_share.titleLabel.alpha = 0;
    twitter_share.tag = 20;
    [twitter_share setTitle:@"test!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap_twt = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinButtonTap:)];
    tap_twt.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [twitter_share addGestureRecognizer:tap_twt];
    [tap_twt release];

    [annotationView addSubview:twitter_share];


- (void) handlePinButtonTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) gestureRecognizer.view;
    MKAnnotationView *av = (MKAnnotationView *)[btn superview];
    id<MKAnnotation> ann = av.annotation;
    NSLog(@"handlePinButtonTap: ann.title=%@", ann.title);

    NSString *testBtn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [btn titleLabel]];

    NSLog(@"handlePinButtonTap: btn title=%@", testBtn);
    }
```

Log:

```
handlePinButtonTap: btn title=<UIButtonLabel: 0x70a14d0; frame = (0 3; 29 22); text = 'test!'; clipsToBounds = YES; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x70a6930>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a double-release error somewhere, which means your `title` string has been deallocated too soon, and its memory has been taken by another object (the `CALayer`). Search for `NSZombieEnabled` or just `xcode zombies` and you should be able to turn on zombie detection which will give you more information.

Comment: Found it! Thank you. All I had to do was use `btn.titleLabel.text` instead of `[btn titleLabel]`

Comment: Not actually the correct answer to the question. Jacob did better at spotting the simple mistake.

Answer (score 3):

This looks fine, although you seem to have a misconception about what `-titleLabel` returns.

`-titleLabel` returns a `UILabel` instance -> To retrieve the *text string contained within the `UILabel`, you have to call the `-text` getter.*